# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with spring backend, angular app and nginx

Tags: angular, spring, cors

I'm struggling with CORS headers.
I have 2 EC2 instances with nginx, one for the frontend with angular, one for the backend with spring

When frontend is calling this resource:

```
Request URL: https://backend.myhost.com/v1/assignments
Access-Control-Request-Origin: https://myhost.com/
Authorization: Basic somebasicauth
Content-Type: application/json
```

I've got:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.myhost.com/v1/assignments' from origin 
'https://myhost.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource.
```

I thought with my spring config everything should be ok. I'm not sure where the error is.

This is my Spring config:

```
 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "HEAD", "DELETE")
            .allowedOrigins("https://myhost.com", "http://backend.myhost.com")
            .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access- 
                Control-Request-Method",
                    "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
            .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow- 
            Credentials").allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
           }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .cors().and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
}
```

Controller:

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Messages successfully sent"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Sanitization error, malicious input", response = 
    ErrorDetailsDto.class)
    })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Send assingments",
        notes = "This method creates assignment")
    @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody() @Validated final 
    AssignmentDto dto) {
      some code
    }
```

Angular Interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.spinnerService.requestStarted();
request = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('user:pw'),
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Request-Origin': 'https://myhost.com/'
  }
});
return this.handler(next, request);
}
```

Request:

```
public postAssignments(): Observable<any> {
this.requestBody = this.wichtelDataHandler.getDto();
return this.http.post<any>('https://backend.myhost.com/v1/assignments', 
this.requestBody, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

there are no special settings in nginx config file for cors.

What do I need to change, that request is not denied?

Comment: I'd like to have feedback for the downvote to improve further question. What can i do better? I thought the problem statement was clear. Only needed code to understand was provided with minimum need informations. What else can I do better?

Answer (score -1):

Just change in Spring Config to

```
       .allowedOrigins("*")
```

Comment: I know I can do this but my goal is only to allow my known origins